# Why does tumblr jquery ui addclass easing work in preview but not blog

Tags: jquery-ui, css, tumblr, jquery-hover

I have some jquery javascript that is supposed to animate the height of a post after a certain amount of time. Works like a charm in Tumblr's in browser editor/previewer ("customize link"). But it fails on the real blog. Checked the source, its there. Here's the URL. view-source:http://wmmmd.tumblr.com/

Here is the add class animate javascript.

```
var hoverTimer;
       $(".post").hover(
        function() {
            var self = this;
            hoverTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                $(self).addClass("postFullHeight",2000);
            }, 1000);
        },
        function() {
            clearTimeout(hoverTimer);
        }
       );
```

What do you think guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from inspecting the code on your webpage, the class 'postFullHeight' is indeed getting added after two seconds.

Class `postFullHeight` is just adding height `100%`. Browser seems to be having problem picking up height 100% but if I change it to absolute number like `700px`. it works just fine.

> **UPDATE**

Based on discussions in comments there are two options you can try.

1. In the  `postFullHeight` try setting the `height : auto;` to see if it works. I should ideally set the height to natural height based on its contents.
2. If that doesn't work, try wrapping all the contents inside it in one div with a particular id, and then you can set the height of `.post` by caculating the height of inside div using the [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) function on inner DIV.

Comment: ah, well i need to calculate how tall tall the post ought to be and then tell it to change to that much height... any thoughts? Because if they all because 700 it would sort of be an effect I am not ok with

Comment: That's right, I just used 700px as an example. So you want to set the height to 100% contents of the .post div? If so do you set a fixed height on all posts to begin with?

Comment: no, some of them are a photo with a caption, others a long (maybe 1000px) depending on how many images are vertically stacked, you know? So it is variable, which is why i was using 100% -- is there a way to run a lil jquery or js to just figure out this.attr(height-before-being formatted into the box)

Comment: worked like a charm as soon as i took out my css3 transition css